# AjaxProxy don't send request to server in ExtJS TreeStore

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've defined a TreeStore-Implementation but in FireBug I don't see a request to my server and don't see data. If I uncomment the root-attribute and comment out the proxy-attribute my data ist displayed. What could be the reason?

Thanks!

```
Ext.define('PM.store.Projects', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'PM.model.Project',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/projectTree.json',
    }

    /*root: {
        name: 'Demo',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Test',
                leaf: true,
            },
        ],
    },*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly load the store. Try autoLoad: true and see if it will make the request.